# convert pdf to img not work (html2canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

Hello I have a plugin that works very well ... but when I want to convert PDF, only captures the div and not the content =/

I'm using html2canvas (https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) and my code is as follows:

```
                  <div id="divCapture">
                        <object class="form-controlPDF" data="my.pdf" type="application/pdf" height="500px">
                        </object>
                      </div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%" id="captur" onclick="capture();">Capture</button>                  

function capture() {
        $('#divCapture').html2canvas({
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        }
        });
    }
```

Comment: yeah, interesting. I can confirm it doesn't work with the pdf.js demo's passed into the test console at http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/screenshots.html either.

Comment: it seemed obvious to work ... unfortunately I will have to look for another solution ... you know any other solution to transform a pdf page to image? tks

Comment: I can answer with a way to convert it to svg if that will help..

Comment: Oh, yeah! You can give me the code? I found this http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/learning/helloworld.html, but I could not spend another url PDF .. have to use such a CORS....

Comment: was referring to http://pramodhkp.github.io/pdf2svg/ , also the proxy on the html2canvas site worked for me to the get cross domain functioning.